# Convertion from NFA to DFA

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I have converted nfa to dfa. But when I checked with some examples, it looks like it is wrong.

```
This is the full question.
Convert the nfa defined by
δ(q0, a) = {q0, q1}
δ(q1, b) = {q1, q2}
δ(q2, a) = {q2}
δ(q1, λ) = {q1, q2}
with initial state q0 and final state q2 into an equivalent dfa.
```

First, I made a table.

```
             a          b
ɸ            ɸ          ɸ
{q0}         {q0,q1}    ɸ
{q1}         ɸ          {q1,q2}
{q2}         {q2}       ɸ
{q0,q1}      {q0,q1}    {q1,q2}
{q1,q2}      {q2}       {q1,q2}
{q0,q2}      {q0,q1,q2} ɸ
{q0,q1,q2}   {q0,q1,q2} {q1,q2}
```

Finally, I have drawn dfa according to table above.
[image]
The bold line is accepting state.

Thanks for your help/

Comment: The sample input strings you used to disprove your transformation would be helpful in figuring out where your error is.  Otherwise I'd need to re-solve the problem myself from scratch.

Comment: @Ertai87 One disprove was that when I did a->λ, it is q2 in nfa. However, in my dfa it does not go.

Comment: Is \lambda a character in your language?  I don't see it in your transition chart or in your graphical diagram.  I'm not quite sure what \lambda represents.

Comment: @Ertai87 lambda is not a character. It's just a null thing

Comment: Transitioning on no input fundamentally violates the concept of a Finite State Machine (FSM).  You can have a "null character" (a character which is defined to semantically represent "null input") which is acceptable, but then that character is still a character in the language.  Is that what \lambda is?  If so, then you need to include \lambda in your transition table just like a and b.

Comment: @Ertai87 I just found that i have miswritten my transition table because of null character. Big thanks for your comment!

Comment: Just for bookkeeping purposes I'm going to convert this discussion into an answer that you can accept to close your question so others don't jump in thinking the question is still active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have 3 symbols in your language: a, b, and \lambda.  But your transition table only has the symbols a and b.  You need to add \lambda to your transition table and integrate that into your diagram.  That should help some.